# How Can I Submit Information To an HTML Form With Go?

Tags: forms, http, go, https

My Go code currently looks like

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)
func main() {
        site := "http://127.0.0.1";
        page := "form.php";
        data := url.Values{};
        data.Set("username", "username");
        data.Set("message", "msg");
        data.Set("parent", "num");
        u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(site);
        u.Path = page;
        urlStr := u.String();
        client := &http.Client{};
        r, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, urlStr, strings.NewReader(data.Encode()));
        r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=\"XXXXXXX\"");
        r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        resp, _ := client.Do(r);
        fmt.Println(resp.Status);
}
```

But for some reason when it gets ran it doesn't submit to the form. What is the problem?

Comment: You're currently ignoring multiple errors in your code, including the error returned by the `*Client.Do` method. Start by systematically checking whether the error values you get are non-`nil` and handle the failure cases properly.

Comment: How precisely do you detect that the form is not submitted? Some TCP sniffing tool?

Comment: @jub0bs I just checked for errors whenever possible and nothing changed

Comment: @kostix Whenever a form is submitted it enters information to an SQL database table